# Creating List-file with CMake and Objdump

Tags: cmake, objdump

is there anyway to say cmake to genrate .lst files with objdump in the same dir as the other  compiled object-files? i want to have a list-file of each src-file.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want and what you have tried?

Comment: i want to creat a list-file for each source file. i could write a batchfile and excute it from cmake, but its not effectiv. so i thoght it would be better if i could make CMake to generate a list-file from the src in the same dir as it compile src. so i finally have something like this.  Src-Dir->           CMakeFiles->Proj.elf.dir->main.c.obj and main.lst

Comment: Any progress on this? I would be interested as well. I would like CMake to run objdump on my .elf.